# Why do my links not work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hyperlink

The links on the right side are supposed to be for categories.
The first **three** links work but why do all the links after that not work?
When you click on them nothing happens.
The mouse doesn't change to a finger when you move your mouse over it.

http://pinoydirectory.com/2011/directory/index.php

I removed the styling, simplified the URLs for debugging, but the links still do not work. Why?
The links work in Internet Explorer 8 but they don't work in Firefox 4.0.1

Comment: Works fine for me.  Firefox 4.0.1.  For example, "Angel Skin Aethstetics" and "Bidets from Delia" work just fine.

Comment: I was going to try and answer this, but Firefox just takes soooo long to load up :(

Comment: @Hexel C - It doesn't work in Firefox 3.6.17. I'm not a web designer but try to select a text in the right menu, it's overlapped by the table on the left so Beno is probably right.

Comment: I would advise not to use tables to display this data. A <ul> list would be better suited for it.

Comment: I copied the file and am still trying to solve the problem on another copy. I found that if I removed the rowspan from the second column all the links work. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: @Ryan S. Good thought on using lists, I usually do do that - I did on the main navigation - but I just didn't remember to use it for this particular case.

Beno got the answer. It was the overlap in my layout.

Comment: @Hexel C it might be worth converting, if you want your content found in search engines, among many other reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take out the

```
table, tr, td {
    position: relative;
}
```

this is causing some overlap in your layout

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Lol if only I didn't have to wait three more minutes for me to mark this as correct! Hours of troubleshooting on my own saved :P

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you fix the errors here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpinoydirectory.com%2F2011%2Fdirectory%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with your table form the left and the css you have for it's tds.
If you remove the:

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
```

from `site_styles.css (line 29)` the links will work ok.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
 `table, tr, td {
    position: relative;
}`

from `site_styles.css`

The `tr` on your left that wraps the pagination and other text is flowing over to the left and covering the links.

Answer (score -1):

All of your links have href="index.php".  You should change index.php to be where you want those links to go. In my testing, the cursor does change to a pointer.

Comment: only on the first 3 links, not the other ones.

Comment: I know, I had them different but for debugging purposes I changed them all to the same so as to remove the possibility that the URL of the links were the culprit.

I'm using Firefox 4.0.1 and only the three first links work. The rest on the right column don't work. If I open it in IE 8 it does work. What are you using?